# What is the best way to hash something in PHP with a key?

Tags: php, hash

I made a game based off luck, and to prove it's fair the result of the game is hashed and shown to the user before it even starts. After the game, the key used to hash the result will be given so the user could verify the game was not manipulated.

What is the best way I can hash something in PHP with a key (made of random bytes)? I'm looking for something secure and fast.

Comment: Hashing doesn't use a key, do you mean encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Without an agreed upon metric of success, "best" is subjective ... at best.  ;-)

Picking from two built-in [PHP hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) algorithms, I suggest you use `md5` for speed, or `sha256` if you are *really* worried about collisions:

```
$data = "some string of characters that serializes or represents game state/score";
$hash = hash('md5', $data);
```

Comment: Where is the key that the program gives to the user so they can verify the result?